# android : control installation process

Tags: android, service, packagemaker, installation-package

I want to Create one simple app witch is display a dialog box with 2 buttons YES and No witch ask to user that they want to install new application ? when user install a new application in android device.if user press YES button then application have permission to install and if user press NO button then new application installation is going cancel.
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

The all over idea is as follows.

your app should have intent receiver which will here for broadcast intent

ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL

Then In on receive method  you can implement your logic.

This is just the faint idea.Might be helpful to you for further r and d.